Sum of series using trigonometry
Here's a series:
$$S=\sqrt{\frac{1}2}.\sqrt{\frac{1}2+\sqrt{\frac{1}2}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}2+\sqrt{\frac{1}2+\sqrt{\frac{1}2}}}...$$
I was told that it can be solved using some kind of trigonometric substitution, but I haven't gotten anywhere with it. Any input will be appreciated.

That's not a series.

Most probably you mean $\sqrt{\frac{1}2}.\sqrt{\frac{1}2+\frac 12\sqrt{\frac{1}2}}.\sqrt{\frac{1}2+\frac 12\sqrt{\frac{1}2+\frac 12\sqrt{\frac{1}2}}}...$
This product can be handled using a trigonometric substitution.
You may ask another question.
